# Slow rise time in power supply

Tags: power-supply, rise-time, undervoltage

Does power supply slow rise time affect the UVLO start threshold voltage to turn on the IC (tps54316mpwprep)?

Comment: There are usually two UVLO numbers: one for rising and one for falling (hysteresis.) Either way, there may be a need for a certain period of time for the power supply to come up. And if there are several supply rails, then there will be a requirement regarding which must come up before others. I don't want to review the datasheet for you. I'll leave that to others. Just writing a note, is all.